# Angular 8 - Routing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to understand how routing works and i'll explain you my project in short summary.

After login, user is navigated to dashboard and there on the sidebar 2 navlinks are displayed: /projects and /training.

Those 2 routes need to be displayed right next to sidebar but instead it is opening new page with that route. How can i achieve this?

I have tried with setting router outlet on the place on which project and training should display but has no logic, I tried with setting name for router outlet but either that did not work.

Routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'project-list', component: ProjectListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'training', component: TrainingComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

App component

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Menu component ( sidebar )

```
<div class="w-100 container-fluid">
  <div class="row page-container">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div
      class="d-none d-md-block"
      [ngClass]="activate ? 'sidebar-expanded' : 'hide-menu'"
      id="sidebar"
    >
      <ul class="sidebar-nav list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <uhura-logo [activate]="activate"></uhura-logo>
        </li>
        <li>
          <uhura-navigation [activate]="activate"></uhura-navigation>
        </li>
        <div class="toggle-container" (click)="toggleClass()">
          <a class="icons-menu typcn" [ngClass]="activate ? 'typcn-chevron-left': 'typcn-chevron-right'">
          </a>
        </div>
        <li>
          <uhura-account></uhura-account>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-10">
          HERE ROUTES SHOULD BE DISPLAYED
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nav component which is nested inside sidebar

```
<div class="navigation-container">
  <div *ngIf="activate" class="nav-info">
    <p>Navigation</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav flex-column nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/project-list" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
        true}">
        <span class="typcn typcn-folder"></span>
        <span *ngIf="activate">Projects</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/training" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:
        true}">
        <span class="typcn typcn-lightbulb"></span>
        <span *ngIf="activate">Training</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to load the training/projects in the sidebar? Then you need to add them as child route of the dashboard

Comment: in app.component add only the <app-menu></app-menu> component and add router-outlet to where you want to display the routed components.

Answer (score 0):

In `app.component.html` you need to put the Menu, NavBar and the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<app-menu></app-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can structure the `AppComponent` like this:

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Plus take care of hiding the sidebar if you are on the login page, something like

```
<app-sidebar *ngIf="isLoggedIn"></app-sidebar>
```

Comment: You are close to what i'm trying to achieve, so on the '/' there should be not sidebar but after user is logged in it is redirected to dashboard with sidebar, and there on dashboard if he choose project on the sidebar it should render on the same page, i might be confused of structure of my project

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested routing.
Try this configuration.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: MenuComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMath: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'project-list'
      },
      {
        path: 'project-list',
        component: ProjectListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'training',
        component: TrainingComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Also place `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside
MenuComponent template where you want to render list or training respectively.

```html
<div class="w-100 container-fluid">
  <div class="row page-container">
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div
      class="d-none d-md-block"
      [ngClass]="activate ? 'sidebar-expanded' : 'hide-menu'"
      id="sidebar"
    >
      <ul class="sidebar-nav list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <uhura-logo [activate]="activate"></uhura-logo>
        </li>
        <li>
          <uhura-navigation [activate]="activate"></uhura-navigation>
        </li>
        <div class="toggle-container" (click)="toggleClass()">
          <a class="icons-menu typcn" [ngClass]="activate ? 'typcn-chevron-left': 'typcn-chevron-right'">
          </a>
        </div>
        <li>
          <uhura-account></uhura-account>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- sidebar -->
    <div class="col-10">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modify navigation component to something like that

```html
<div class="navigation-container">
  <div *ngIf="activate" class="nav-info">
    <p>Navigation</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav flex-column nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[../project-list]" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span class="typcn typcn-folder"></span>
        <span *ngIf="activate">Projects</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"  [routerLink]=["../training"] routerLinkActive="active">
        <span class="typcn typcn-lightbulb"></span>
        <span *ngIf="activate">Training</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope it helped.